# PHP-FPM - Nginx - phpMyAdmin - 502 bad gateway

Tags: 12.10, configuration, php, nginx, phpmyadmin

I have installed and configured PHP-FPM, Nginx, and then phpMyAdmin.  When I access the main site everything works fine but as soon as I go to http://mysite.com/phpmyadmin I get a 502 bad gateway error.

When I look in my error logs I see the following error repeated throughout:
*(111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xx.xx.xx.xx*

Here is my default.conf for nginx:
http://pastebin.com/YFEvAw81

I have tried many different configurations that I have found from users that have had the same issue but can't seem to get any of them to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found under [step 7](http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-nginx-with-php5-and-php-fpm-and-mysql-support-lemp-on-ubuntu-12.04-lts) that you have to change the reference of the fastcgi_pass to your unix socket (ex:  /tmp/php5-fpm.sock) instead of it listening to 127.0.0.1:9000

This has been a great learning experience, since I don't know the innards of Ubuntu/Unix

Answer (score 6):

Change the fastcgi_pass line (line 52 in your example) to:

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
```

This is valid for Ubuntu 12.10